# SQL Server connection string attempts to connect to wrong database

Tags: vba, sql-server-2005, database-connection

I am having a problem with either my connection string in my Access front end OR the security on the SQL Server DB. I'm betting its security, and i'm a novice at this.

I've setup my login on the SQL Server against my DB and assigned it to a role with execute permissions against that DB.

MY VBA code is below along with the error message. Essentially, it appears to try and connect to another db on the server.

```
Public Sub ExecuteProc(ProcName As String)

    On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection

    Dim stConnect As String

    ''On Error Resume Next

    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    stConnect = "Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase;UID=MyUser;PWD=MyPWD;"


    Debug.Print stConnect

    cnn.Open stConnect

    With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = ProcName
    .Execute
    End With

PROC_EXIT:
    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    cnn.Close
    Set cnn = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Exit Sub

PROC_ERR:

    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    Debug.Print Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    Resume PROC_EXIT

End Sub
```

ERROR:

```
-2147467259
[Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]The server principal "MyUser" is not able to access the database "AnotherDatabase" under the current security context.
```

The server is SQL 2005 SP4, the Access app is installed on a Windows 7 machine. The Windows 7 machine has the following drivers installed:

SQL Native Client 2005.90.5000.00

SQL Server 6.01.7601.17514

I've checked the Surface Area Configuration and it is setup for remote connections using TCP/IP and named pipes. There are other applications which connect to other databases on the server, and they all work fine.

I'm not sure where to look. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the stored procedure itself to see if it is querying against that other database. It is totally possible to do a cross-database query, and you'd need permissions to read that other database as well then.

Comment: Thanks Urit.. That was the actual problem.

Comment: THANKS!  I was having this same problem and it seemed impossible. But now, it makes perfect sense!